Filter and Antenna S11 measurement
I have this circuit below where a BLE chip is connected to the filter and then to the antenna, I've been requested to find S11 from the chip output (for the filter and antenna) when I use ENA to find S11 the value is very big (around -3dB) but when I check filter and antenna individually S11 for both of them is ok (around -15dB), Antenna receives and transmits without any problem so I don't think there is impedance mismatching, anyone could help what should I do to make the measurement correct?

